# Error en codificación python

Tags: python, python-2.x, codificación, nlp

Estoy realizando NLP en python, para ello necesito extraer las stop_words del idioma español, y lo realizó de la siguiente manera:

```
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
stop_words = (stopwords.words("spanish"))
stop_words = [sw.encode('ascii','ignore').decode('UTF8') for sw in stop_words]
print stop_words
```

pero al realizar la impresion de las palabras las palabras que llevan acento les quita la letra y el acento y obtengo algo como esto :

```
estn,
tendrs,
est,
ests,
```

La verdad no se que estoy haciendo mal o cual sea el error.

Comment: porque necesitas `encode` y `decode`? el `ignore` es el que está quitando esas letras

Comment: Pero si le quito el ignore aun así me sale error!

UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe1' in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: por eso te pregunté para que necesitas hacerle `encode` y `decode`?